# How to integrate authentication and use libvncserver 0.9.14 with novnc?

Tags: c++, vnc

I am developing an FRB application for a project at my company using libvncserver version 0.9.14. I have successfully integrated libvncserver into my project, and now the viewer can connect to my VNC server.

However, I am facing difficulties when adding authentication to my application. I want to prompt the user to provide a password when connecting to the VNC server. I have looked through the libvncserver documentation, but I couldn't find much detailed information on how to integrate authentication.

My first question is: How can I integrate authentication into libvncserver version 0.9.14? I have tried using some functions, but I'm unsure if I'm using them correctly. I really need a specific example or guidance on how to achieve this.

My second question is: I want to integrate libvncserver with novnc to create a web-based VNC viewer. I have tried using novnc, but I'm unsure about how to integrate it with my libvncserver. I have searched for documentation or examples on integrating libvncserver with novnc, but I couldn't find specific information.

Thank you all for reading my question.